# Create model with resourceful controller

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-artisan

I know I can create a model with controller by using the command `php artisan make:model Task -c`and I also can create a resourceful controller with `php artisan make:controller TasksController -r`. Is there a way to create both a model with a resourceful controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this without using packages. If you run `php artisan make:model --help` you will find the `options` that you can add to the command.

```
php artisan make:model --help

Options:
-c, --controller  Create a new controller for the model.
-r, --resource    Indicated if the generated controller should be a resource controller
```

So if you run it with both the `c` and the `r` flag, it will generate the `model`, along with a resource `controller`:

`php artisan make:model Task -c -r`

**Note**: this works for versions `>=5.3`!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, usually I do `php artisan make:model Task -mc` but when I tried to run `php artisan make:model Task -mcr` it gave me an error, guess I never tought passing the options one by one,

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at a generator package.

- https://github.com/amranidev/scaffold-interface
- https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a simple method which 100% works for me in laravel 7

```
php artisan make:model ModelName -mr
```

This command will create a new model with resourceful controller as well as with migration

`-m` denotes for migrations 
`-r` creates resourceful controller and associate it with model

hope this is usefull for you

Answer (score 0):

example

```
php artisan make:model Product -c

  -a, --all             Generate a migration, seeder, factory, and resource controller for the model
  -c, --controller      Create a new controller for the model
  -f, --factory         Create a new factory for the model
      --force           Create the class even if the model already exists
  -m, --migration       Create a new migration file for the model
  -s, --seed            Create a new seeder file for the model
  -p, --pivot           Indicates if the generated model should be a custom intermediate table model
  -r, --resource        Indicates if the generated controller should be a resource controller
      --api             Indicates if the generated controller should be an API controller
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the previous answer. Sorry.